# I need to use profiler in my IDE

Tags: java, profiling, rsa

I am using RSA7 as IDE, I need to use profiler in my IDE for memory analysis.

Can any one suggest me

1. From where I can free download it?
2. How can I use it with RSA7?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't absolutely need it to be integrated in your IDE, JProfiler is a great one and runs outside the IDE. Although it can run in most IDE's, that you should check on their site [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html)

Remark: It's not Free, but a profiler pays for it selfs, once you sum up the time it saved you then you understand that it is well spend money!

Answer (score 0):

[VisualVM](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html) comes with the JDK and includes a pretty good memory profiler. Also not integrated with RSA, but doesn't really need to be.

Comment: Thanks Michael,
I have already had JDK6 in my system. but In bin folder I am unable to see jvisualvm.exe to start. 

what should I do now?

Comment: @ashwani66476 It's in the bin directory of the JDK (not the JRE). Also, it wasn't distributed with Java 6 right from the beginning; I think it was added in Update 07.

Comment: Okay, Thanks Michael for your kind support. Thanks a lot.